# How to extract data from the String in splunk?

Tags: splunk

I was given a log from splunk and I want to get a particular data in the middle of the string and use it for the dashboard. For example:

msg="somestring1 somestring2 500 somestring3 ..."

How do I get the value 500?

Sorry, I am not expert in splunk. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have real (sanitized) events to share?  It's a lot easier to develop a working parse using genuine data.  That said, you have a couple of options: `| eval xxxxx=mvindex(split(msg," "), 2)` if the target is always the third word; `| rex field=msg "\S+\s+\S+\s+(?<xxxxx>\S+)"` again, if the target is always the third word.  There are other options, too, depending on the nature of msg.

Comment: thanks RichG. I thought I have replied to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.2.0/SearchReference/Rex) command.

Example usage:

`... | rex field=message "\S+ \S+ (?<extracted_field>\d+) \S+" | stats count by extracted_field`

Comment: @arn-arn if this works, could you accept the answer. :)